# How store objects in MongoDb without assembly fully qualified name

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I store item that contains fields like Dictionary
In mongo this field has _t = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,[Namespace.MyType, Namespace, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b48272fdae8cae]]

I don't need Version and PublicKeyToken and farther this be a trouble with next version of assembly
How can I store data with _t property like System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,[Namespace.MyType]]?

Comment: You need to do custom serialization. Your data is very non portable if you're storing .NET types like Dictionary. Is that Ok?

Answer (score 0):

The type discriminator is used for inheritance and resolving declared type to stored type.
If you have a concrete class with a concrete property, you should not need a discriminator.

Let's say you have a property on a class:

```
public class Foo : MyBase{
   ...
   public string Title {get;set;}
}

public class Bar: MyBase{
   ...
   public string Title {get;set;}
}
```

The driver might be able to map that IN to a string array and store in mongodb
    {_id: ..., Title: "Hello" }

On the way OUT though, the driver has to decide what the BSON array would become. Absent a type discriminator, should it generate an instance of : Foo? Bar? MyBase?

If you have a class that has-a concrete dictionary rather than is-a dictionary, you can avoid much of this.